# `add.lines` parameter not working in `stargazer` for data frame?

Tags: r, regression, stargazer, xtable, texreg

I have stored the output of a regression in a dataframe like so:

```
> df
                   beta        se    p
air_quality  -0.0535707 0.5251661 0.92
```

I know that I can export the regression results using `stargazer` and the regression object, and the use the `add.lines` parameter to write my own goodness-of-fit statistics. For example:

```
stargazer(model1,
          add.lines = list(c("No. of Observations", "388"),
                           c("No. of Males", "43")))
```

or using `custom.gof.rows` in `texreg`:

```
texreg(model1, 
       custom.gof.rows = list(c("No. of Observations", "388"),
                           c("No. of Males", "43")))
```

The problem is that neither does `add.lines` in `stargazer` work or `custom.gof.rows` in `texreg` because it does not allow dataframes.

I'd like to know if this is possible using a dataframe like I do.